# Centos/RHEL 8 systemd service not able to reference script from custom location

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

I am trying to create a systemd service, for a simple script present in a location (other than /usr/local/bin..)

Below script is under `/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

MAX=500
i=0;
while true
do
i=$((i+1));
sleep 2
echo "$i = $(date)"
if [ $i == $MAX ]; then
  exit 0;
fi;
done;
fi
```

I created simple service named `usr-print.service` under `/etc/systemd/system/`. The content of the file is

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple print service
After=network.target

[Service]

Type=simple
Restart=always
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

ExecStart=/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when i start the service using `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl start usr-print.service` i get below exception.

```
● usr-print.service - Simple print service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/usr-print.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-08-02 06:10:39 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 1504 ExecStart=/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1504 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Simple print service.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: usr-print.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 02 06:10:39 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Simple print service.
```

But if I move the script and update the usr-print.service file with  `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/test.sh` the service starts as expected.

Is there a way to user the `/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh` path in service file?

Centos 7 - `ExecStart=/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh` in service file works (shell is running)

Centos/RHEL 8 - `ExecStart=/home/vagrant/temp/test.sh` in service file DOES NOT work.

**Update:**

Looks like the SELinux not able to execute that script though it had Execute permissions.

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/lib/systemd/systemd from execute access on the file /home/vagrant/temp/test.sh.
                                                              
*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that systemd should be allowed execute access on the user-print-service file by default.
    Then you should report this as a bug.
    You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
    Do allow this access for now by executing:
       # ausearch -c '(-service)' --raw | audit2allow -M my-service
       # semodule -X 300 -i my-service.pp
```

noticed a ticket related to this in Redhat: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1832231

Comment: Is /home a separate filesystem that is mounted noexec, by any chance?

Comment: It is not a sperate filesystem. I was using vagrant and virtual box, it was the default user vagrant.

Comment: I just saw the update; allowing a specific execution path is a much better idea than disabling SELinux altogether.

Comment: I agree. i was working on a requirement to start a script as systemd service. it worked in centos 7 box not on rhel 8. so explored the documentation. Disabling SELinux in permissive mode is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

One possible apporach,for running in local is to use below

`getenforce` was enabled enforcing mode on SELinux

`sudo setenforce 0` disabled it and put in permissive mode. now the service runs.

But this is not recommended in production env.